# I need a barcode in a PDF/A

Tags: pdfx, pdf-a, pst-barcode, qrcode

as in the title, I need a (simple 128) barcode and I need the PDF/A standard. I know how to do both separately. But pdfx won't run with latex so I cannot create a DVI and so on, which I need for the pst-barcode package:

`! pdfTeX error (\pdfmapline): not allowed in DVI mode (\pdfoutput <= 0). \pdfmapline`

Is there a way to have a bar code and PDF/A without pst-barcode that works with pdfLatex? Thank you very much!

Edit: using the code in the answer below the following terminal output is produced (truncated a bit):

```
C:\test\lat>xelatex --shell-escape -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -z 0" xeBar.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 2.9.7380 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(xeBar.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
[...]
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\psdextra.
def")
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/colorprofiles\co
lorprofiles.sty"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/colorprofiles\co
lorprofiles.tex"))
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/stringenc\se-asc
ii-print.def")
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pdfx\AdobeColorPro
files.tex")
** pdfx: No file xeBar.xmpdata . Metadata will be incomplete!
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xmpincl\xmpincl.st
y")
Using XMP template file: pdfa.xmp
)
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pst-barcode\pst-ba
rcode.sty"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pstricks\pstricks.
sty"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty
")
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\pst-xkey
.tex"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.st
y"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.
tex"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils
.tex"))))
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstrick
s.tex"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.
tex" `pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
[...]
`PSTricks' v2.97  <2019/05/11> (tvz,hv)

("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks\p
stricks.con"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\xdvipdf
mx.cfg"))
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks\p
stricks.con"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\xdvipdf
mx.cfg"
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
)))
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.
tex")
>>> Loading XeTeX special macros

("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstrick
s-xetex.def"))
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pst-barcode\pst-
barcode.tex" `PST-barcode' v0.18, 2017/08/22 (tb,hv)
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/marginnote\marginn
ote.sty")))
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backen
d-xdvipdfmx.def") (xeBar.aux)
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd")
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/hyperref\nameref.s
ty"
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.
sty")
("C:\Users\Dev06\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/gettitlestring\g
ettitlestring.sty")) (xeBar.out) (xeBar.out) [1] (xeBar.aux) )stdin -> stdout
[1
xdvipdfmx:warning: Could not find any valid object.
xdvipdfmx:warning: Filtering file via command -->mgs.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile="C:/Users/Dev06/AppData/Local/Temp/mikDCFC.tmp" "C:/Users/Dev06/AppData/Local/Temp/mikDCFB.tmp" -c quit<-- failed.
xdvipdfmx:warning: Image format conversion for PSTricks failed.
xdvipdfmx:warning: Interpreting special command pst: (ps:) failed.
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> at page="1" position="(148.712, 595.198)" (in PDF)
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> xxx "pst:  tx@Dict begin STP newpath 0.8 SLW 0 0 0  setrgbcolor   gs"
]
11723 bytes written
```

Comment: create the barcode as external image, e.g. with a standalone document and then include it as graphics.

Comment: Try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/barracuda

Comment: For example http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/code128/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PSTricks packages with XeLaTeX, which is also supported by `pdfx`. According to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf) of `pdfx` (page 1 in a footnote) you need the following command:

`xelatex --shell-escape -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -z 0" <filename>.tex`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(2.5,1in)
\psbarcode{01335583}{includetext}{ean8}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but after some warnings, would be too many to post here. I just get an empty pdf with a page number

Comment: @Namal did you try with exactly the example document from this answer without any changes? And running XeLaTeX with the command line as specified? If yes, what is the first warning or error that you get? If no, could you try with this example document to see if that works? Also it might be useful to know which version of XeLaTeX, pdfx and pst-barcode you use.

Comment: I uploaded the log [here](http://txt.do/18l13). Also, yes, I have used your example without any changes.

Comment: @Namal I added the terminal output into your question. I'm not sure what the problem is exactly, maybe someone that uses MikTeX can clarify.

Comment: I tried it with texlive on linux and it works without any issue. Still I decided to make a standelone from the code and to include it into my document, since I have more experience with pdflatex.